# Traefix v1.7 static certificates and dynamic acme certificates

Tags: docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik, acme

I am using **traefik:1.7.6-alpine** in docker in swarm mode. I need to specify static ssl certificates and other self-managed acme certificates.

This is the error I get when lifting the container:

```
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#collected-data\n"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=error msg="Failed to read new account, ACME data conversion is not available : unexpected end of JSON input"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=error msg="Unable to add ACME provider to the providers list: unable to get ACME account : unexpected end of JSON input"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Address::443 TLS:0xc000288630 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0006a45c0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Preparing server traefik &{Address::8080 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0006a4560} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc0006a4580} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Starting provider configuration.ProviderAggregator {}"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :8080"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"arkaangel.com\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":false,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false,\"Network\":\"\",\"SwarmModeRefreshSeconds\":15}"
time="2020-06-18T02:45:52Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
```

This is my traefik.toml

```
debug = true
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
        address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.https]
        address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]
            [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
                certFile = "/path/to/first/first.crt"
                keyFile = "/path/to/first/first.key"
            [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
                certFile = "/path/to/second/second.crt"
                keyFile =  "/path/to/second/second.key"
[api]
  dashboard = true
  [api.statistics]
    recentErrors = 10
[docker]
  exposedbydefault = false
  watch = true
  domain = "mydomain.com"

[acme]
email = "myemail@gmail.com"
storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging = true
onHostRule = true
    [acme.httpChallenge]
       entryPoint = "http"
    [[acme.domains]]
       main = "third-site.com"
```

And this is how I mount the acme.json file in the docker-compose to keep the generated certificates:

```
volumes:
./traefik/acme/acme.json:/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
```

the **acme.json** file has **600** permissions and owner **root:root**.

In addition to the configuration shown, things that I have tried without being able to generate the certificate:

1. not map the **acme.json** file but the parent folder so that traefik create the **acme.json** file **(failed)**
2. do not map any volume for the **acme.json** so that it is lost when the container is removed. **(failed)**
3. changed the owner to the file **acme.json** to **myuser: myuser**, so from the container the user **1000** is shown as owner **(failed)**

Comment: You error message is more related to an invalid json > unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @abestrad I know, but the file is empty, it was created with **touch acme.json**, it is an empty file, how can it have an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was able to solve the error of: **"Failed to read new account, ACME data conversion is not available : unexpected end of JSON input"**, was writing inside the file **acme.json** `{}`, apparently when trying to read an empty file and parsing it to json it gave an error.

**Summary:**
when creating the **acme.json** on the host to be mapped then you have to do:

```
touch acme.json
echo '{}'> acme.json
chmod 600 acme.json
```

Comment: You just solved the problem that had me losing hair for hours. Thank you!